# Is Payapl REST API supporting credit cards outside US and UK?

Tags: rest, paypal

According to the [official website of paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments),

> The REST API supports direct credit card payments, which are credit
>   card payments without a separate web approval flow, in the following
>   countries:
>
> United States
>   United Kingdom

However, my colleague and I tried using the API with credit cards issued in Hong Kong (under VISA and Master, but issued by Hong Kong local banks) and the API works fine for both testing and real account. (yes, we spend a few dolloar to test it)

Have any other tried using REST API on credit cards outside US and UK? Should we switch back to the classic API?

Answer (score 0):

That note refers to the country in which you're *accepting* credit cards (in other words; the country in which your PayPal account is registered), *not* the countries of the card issuer.

Comment: Thanks. You answer the question, but for the real situation, the testing account accepting credit cards is also opened in Hong Kong. Any idea if that works too?